# How to update a node in Modified Preorder Tree Traversal

Tags: sql, algorithm, mptt

I am using MPTT for storing Hierarchies. The concept for Adding and Deleting is well explained in this [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal](http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/03/16/storing-retrieving-hierarchical-data-in-sql-server-database.aspx) link.

How do we update a particular node and its tree associated with it in Modified preorder tree traversal ? 
For eg:- If i want to move TLA and its hierarchy under TLC. Using sql script how can we do that?

[image]

Any help appreciated .

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on that link - it looks like you update the tree by taking a given root node, and updating all nodes that have both a left value greater than the left value of that root node and a right value less than the right value of that root node.  Seems pretty straightforward.  Does that help?

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide some more details as to what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: i have edited my question. I am trying to write procedure for moving the heirarchy

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to remove the TLA and its hierarchy, then append them recursively to TLC. It requires several SQL statements to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Move the TLA node after the Tech Support node:

```
@TlaLeft = 2
@TlaRight = 7
@TechSupportRight = 18
```

First update the new location of the TLA:

```
UPDATE Tree SET lft = lft + @TlaRight - @TlaLeft + 1, rgt = rgt + @TlaRight - @TlaLeft + 1  WHERE rgt > @TechSupportRight;
```

Second update the TLA itself, and its descendants if any, to the new location:

```
UPDATE Tree SET lft = lft + (@TechSupportRight - @TlaLeft) + 1, rgt = rgt + (@TechSupportRight - @TlaRight) + 1  WHERE lft >= @TlaLeft AND rgt <= @TlaRight;
```

Third update the old TLA location:

```
UPDATE Tree SET lft = lft - (@TlaRight - @TlaLeft ) - 1 WHERE lft > @TlaLeft;
UPDATE Tree SET rgt = rgt - (@TlaRight - @TlaLeft ) - 1 WHERE rgt > @TlaRight;
```

Comment: What if the destination parent is a leaf and has no child ? How to move it then ?